# Possible to drag and drop e-mails to SharePoint list in Outlook?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, sharepoint

When connecting Outlook and a SharePoint document library is it possible to add e-mails from Outlook to the library inside Outlook using drag and drop or some other method? if some sort of addon is needed I'd prefer a really, really simple solution; ie. not a suite of Outlook-SharePoint integration features.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are connecting a SharePoint list to Outlook and you want to store E-Mails in that SharePoint list and exchange them via Drag and Drop?

Comment: That is correct, if you by "exchange" mean 'put them there' so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure SharePoint to receive E-mails, the only easy way would be to forward all your e-mails to that dedicated sharepoint e-mail or I could think of one easy solution: Use the SharePoint webdav feature ("Explorer View"). You could map the network location to a network drive and just drag and drop Outlook items into that folder. SharePoint will display the messages and Outlook will most probably open them from there.

A "drag-and-drop" solution to get just some email's to Sharepoint would need to be custom coded. Think about the implications:

- The mails need to be converted to some web-friendly format (i.e. including sender information etc.)
- The e-mail needs to be stored in SharePoint
- The attachments will need to be stored somewhere else in SharePoint
- The e-mail needs to reference the attachments in some way

If you're into third party solutions, there are some good ones available:

- [SharePoint Outlook integration](http://www.tesl.com/TESL/Solutions/SharePoint+Outlook+integration.htm)

> "allows an easy 'drag and drop' action
>   to copy or move specific emails to
>   document libraries"

- [Colligo Contributor](http://www.colligo.com/products/sharepoint/outlook_add-in.asp)

> "The Outlook Add-in provides a
>   convenient way to synchronize
>   SharePoint document libraries
>   (including sub-folders) with Outlook
>   folders. Users can easily copy or move
>   documents, emails, and attachments
>   between Outlook and SharePoint -
>   either manually with a simple
>   drag-and-drop or automatically using
>   Outlook rules. "

Comment: Looks like there isn't a native solution to this challenge then. Thanx for the links. But please note that the first link to a really old product... :)

Comment: Should have sorted them differently - Colligo is a "known name" so I would go with them if I had to choose. Also try to use Explorer View once and move some E-Mails to a document library of your choice - maybe it even works this simple way.

Comment: I'm sure the "Explorer view" works, it's just that some of my colleagues wants everything inside Outlook...

Comment: Just as a note we decided to add a "Discussion Board" list to our sites and connect that to Outlook; this list supports drag and drop of e-mails to it.

Answer (score 1):

For drag and drop of emails from Outlook to SharePoint we are using [SharePoint Outlook Integration](http://www.sai-innovations.com/sharepoint-outlook-integration.aspx) tool. PageLight also offers [Save Outlook emails to SharePoint](http://www.sai-innovations.com/sharepoint-outlook-integration.aspx) functionality to copy emails and attachments with their Meta data

Answer (score -1):

Outlook does not support drag and drop to any web application including SharePoint Out of the box. This is true for email, attachments and calendar events. The best option is to use the explorer view of SharePoint, but this comes with its own set of challenges like you cannot force metadata OR if the associated content type has required fields the file remains checked-out and invisible to other users.

There are some 3rd party tools which you can trial to see if they meet your requirements like - https://www.konnectemail.com